# iOS UIWebView handle Transfer-Encoding chunked

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I tried to load a webpage with UIWebView but the UIWebView cannot load a resource which the response of the server would return a http header contain the field `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` while I can load it with safari.

Comment: can you past the header of that html page or give the url of that page if we can access it

Comment: @Jageen:for example, the url is https://app.onedesk.com and I find that the get request for `GET https://app.onedesk.com/main/D0F0488B8CB9D6B548B41B3773B2418B.cache.html HTTP/1.1` isn't executed in webview but it is executed in safari

Comment: You mean website can not perform get request from UIWebView but can perform it in safari ?

Comment: @buggeroverflow76 did you get any thing in didFailLoadWithError ?

Comment: @Jageen:You mean website can not perform get request from UIWebView but can perform it in safari ? YES

Comment: did you get any error in didFailLoadWithError

Comment: did you get any thing in didFailLoadWithError ? No. I did receive webViewDidFinishLoad for the request URL:https://app.onedesk.com/. But the problem is that in my webview it doesn't make a call to /main/D0F0488B8CB9D6B548B41B3773B2418B.cache.html after the webview loaded the page `https://app.onedesk.com/`.

Comment: Did you try with wkwebview ? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html

Comment: @Jageen, wkwebview sound interesting. I will try it. Btw, can wkwebview be used in iOS 7 or only available to iOS 8?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66715/discussion-between-jageen-and-bufferoverflow76).